# Can one make MySQL cluster on a unique index rather than a primary key?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, clustered-index, ddl

[The MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) states that:

> When you define a PRIMARY KEY on your table, InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.

But that's not the only possibility, you can cluster off of a unique index instead:

> If you do not define a PRIMARY KEY for your table, MySQL locates the first UNIQUE index where all the key columns are NOT NULL and InnoDB uses it as the clustered index.

It would seem to follow that if I first create a unique index on a table, it will be marked as clustered; I can then create a primary key, and it will be nonclustered:

```
CREATE TABLE Tmp_CUQTest
(
ID1 INT NOT NULL,  -- Desired clustering field
ID2 INT NOT NULL   -- Desired PK field
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CUC_Tmp ON Tmp_CUQTest (ID1);
ALTER TABLE Tmp_CUQTest ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY PK_Tmp (ID2);
```

However, when I inspect the resulting table, my hopes are dashed:

```
Key      Type               Uni  Columns
PRIMARY  BTREE (clustered)  YES  ID2
ID1      BTREE              YES  ID1
```

[Another question here on DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189217/mysql-creating-an-index-in-table-ddl-statement-or-separately) implies that creating an index as part of the `CREATE TABLE` script, rather than afterward, as a separate `CREATE INDEX` statement, may make a difference.  However, I get the same result.

Is there a way to force MySQL to cluster on a unique index of my choice, other than the primary key, or does this "fallback option" only apply to tables with no primary key at all?

Comment: "PK" that is not clustered is just an `UNIQUE` key over `NOT NULL` columns. And there is no INNODB tables with no clustered PK - if no appropriate index exist engine will create the hidden column `UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` and use it as clustered PK.

Comment: @Kondybas: interesting; in MS SQL (where I'm most familiar), secondary indices reference the PK, whether its clustered or not.  Apparently in MySQL, secondary indices reference the clustered key, whether its the PK or merely a unique index.  Is that your understanding?

Comment: As far as I understand Mysql's definition of clustered index : "The InnoDB term for a primary key index." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_clustered_index ) , primary key is always supported by clustered index , and there is no way to have non-clustered primary key

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Clustered index is strictly the same as PK for the INNODB. You have to declare the index as PK to make it clustered. There is no way to separate this two properties from each other in the mysql.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades are you sure? Reading [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017) about non-clustered indexes: *"The pointer from an index row in a nonclustered index to a data row is called a row locator. The structure of the row locator depends on whether the data pages are stored in a heap or a clustered table. For a heap, a row locator is a pointer to the row. **For a clustered table, the row locator is the clustered index key**."*

Comment: @Kondybas: *"Clustered index is strictly the same as PK for the INNODB. You have to declare the index as PK to make it clustered."* Correct but only if the table has a PK. If the table has not a PK, then the clustered index is the first UNIQUE index where all columns are NOT NULL. And if there is no such index, then it's the (auto-created) hidden one.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: pretty sure.  I've tested it: if you create a table with a narrow CPK field and a wide UQ field, then a bunch indices, you get a small table.  With the same data, but a CUQ on the wide field and a NCPK on the narrow field, you get a large table - large in indices, that is.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what you were saying, isn't it, @ypercubeᵀᴹ - that the secondary indices reference the clustered index, whether that's nominally the PK or not.  Then perhaps there *is* no practical difference between the two systems, other than that MS SQL gives you the trivial flexibility to *label* an index PK separately from making it the clustered index.

Comment: Yes, there are very small differences. One, as you say, in MySQL you can't choose the index to be used (if there's a PK, that's it. SQL Server allows choosing any index as clustered).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`PRIMARY KEY`**

- InnoDB has *exactly* one `PRIMARY KEY` on each table.
- The `PRIMARY KEY` is *always* clustered; there *cannot* be any other "clustered" index.
- That PK is either an explicitly stated PK (this is preferred), the first `UNIQUE` key (with certain limitations), or a hidden sequence number (not quite the same as `AUTO_INCREMENT; 6 bytes).
- The PK *is* `UNIQUE` and *is* and index.
- The PK (and other indexes) *may* contain multiple columns ("composite" index.
- The table is structured as a BTree (actually a B+Tree), with all columns present, and BTree is ordered according to the PK.

**Secondary Keys**

- All other indexes are called "secondary indexes".  ("key" == "index")
- The structure is a B+Tree, ordered according to the key
- The "rows" of this BTree contain copies of the column(s) of the `PRIMARY KEY` (that is, the 'clustered index').  This is how the secondary key can get to the row.
- Note that looking up a row via a secondary key requires drilling down two BTrees.  (Unless it is a "covering" index).
- A `UNIQUE KEY` is two things: a secondary key (unless promoted to PK), and a "uniqueness constraint".

**Other notes**

- InnoDB has not concept of a "ROWNUM" or "row locator", unlike some other vendors.  The PK serves as the row locator.
- MySQL has no "Heap" or "Bit" indexes on InnoDB.
- InnoDB has only BTree, SPATIAL, and FULLTEXT; I am not discussion the latter two in this Answer.
- For most purposes, it does not matter whether you create the indexes inside the `CREATE TABLE` statement, or do `CREATE INDEX` later.  Ditto for defining `FOREIGN KEYs`.
- Structurally, the PK+data is a B+Tree; each secondary index is a B+Tree.  These B+Trees look, feel, smell, etc, identical.  The only difference is what you find in the 'rows'.

**`AUTO_INCREMENT`**

- There are many caveats.  It is not necessarily consecutive numbers; there are many ways that gaps can occur.  Only trust that they will be 'unique'.
- `AUTO_INCREMENT` does *not* have to be declared `PRIMARY KEY`, or even `UNIQUE`.

**A trick**.  It is possible to do the following.  Is it what you are fishing for??

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  foo ...,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (foo, id),  -- to get clustering on `foo` and uniqueness (via `id`)
  INDEX(id)               -- sufficient to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy.
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 1):

A primary key is a unique key and an index. So create the PK as the unique index that you want to cluster on.

Create adding an index afterwards and as part of the create table yeild the same result.